# if vectors are linearly independent then their images are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces and suppose  $l\in L(V, W)$. If $v_{1},...,v_{n} \in V$ are linearly independent then can we say that $l(v_{1}),....,l(v_{n}) \in W$ are linearly independent?
What i've tried if $\dim(V)>\dim(W)$ then it's not true and if $\dim(V)\leq \dim(W)$ then linear map $l$ must be an injection.
EDIT::: Note that $v_{1},...,v_{n} \in V$ need not be a basis in that case my assumption fails.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are saying.  A linear transformation takes independent sets to independent sets if and only if it is non-singular.

Comment: The proof is extremely simple. First, a proposition that I'll leave as an exercise:
>Given a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, $T(v)=0_W$ iff $v=0_V$. The rest follows from @Fenris 's answer.

Comment: @K.defaoite what do you mean by $v=0_{V}$ are you saying that $v$ is zero vector or $v$ is the null space?

Comment: @K.defaoite,  i've updated my question can you please give it a look

Answer (score 1):

If $l$ is an injection, the image of a linearly independent set is linearly independent. To see this let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear injection and assume that $S = \{v_1, \cdots, v_n \} \subseteq V$ is linearly independent.

Suppose

$$c_1 T(v_1) + \cdots + c_n T(v_n) = 0$$

Since $T$ is linear, we have

$$T(c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n ) = 0$$

Since $T$ is injective, we have

$$c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0, $$

which gives $c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0$ since $S$ was assumed linearly independent.

Comment: On the other hand, if $l$ is not injective, i.e. has a nontrivial *kernel*, then it doesn't map linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets (specifically e.g.: a one element set of a nonzero element of the kernel is independent while its image, $0$ is not).

Comment: @Berci i've updated my question can you look at it one more time please/